# Show that $P(\tau >n)=e^{-n\lambda}(1+n\lambda)$

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

**Problem:**
Let $X_1, ... ,X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables which are $\mathrm{Pois}(\lambda).$ Let $\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,...,X_n), n\geq 1$ and define

$$S_n =\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \: \: M_n =S_n-n\lambda, \: \: \tau=\inf\{n\geq 1 : S_n \geq 2\}.$$

I have proved that Sn for $n\geq 0$ is a Markov Chain on the set of natural numbers with 0, and that Mn for $n\geq 1$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathscr{F}_n$ for $n\geq 1.$

I now have to show that $P(\tau >n)=e^{-n\lambda}(1+n\lambda)$.

But i'm having a hard time starting on this problem. I know that $S_n \sim\mathrm{ Pois}(n\lambda)$.

Any hints?

Comment: Taking more than n turns to reach 2 is equivalent to not having reached 2 by the nth turn.

Comment: I'm afraid i still dont get it. I understand what $\tau$ and $P(\tau > n)$ means, but having difficulties formalize it in math.

Comment: $P(\tau>n)=P(S_n<2)=P(S_n=0)+P(S_n=1)=e^{-n\lambda}+n\lambda e^{-n\lambda}$

Comment: Do note that "$\tau$ is [...] Poisson distributed with $n\lambda$" doesn't make any sense (in this statement, what is $n$?).